# In JPA2 and Java 10, how do I map the value of an enum to an @Enumerated column?

Tags: java, jpa, enums, jpa-2.0, enumerated-types

I'm using Java 10.  If I define an enum like this

```
public enum MyEnum {
  NAME1("value 1"),
  NAME2("value 2"),
    ...
}
```

and then I have a JPA-mapped database column that is defined by the enum

```
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  private MyEnum status;
```

What else do I need to do to map the value of the enum (e.g. "value 2") to the column "status" instead of the name, which is getting mapped currently?

Comment: Java 10 has not been supported for about 5 years.  Any reason you're stuck on that?

Comment: I would love to upgrade, but it's not my decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *JPA2* really means ***JPA 2.1*** then `AttributeConverter` is the perfect solution.

> A class that implements this interface can be used to convert entity attribute state into database column representation and back again. Note that the X and Y types may be the same Java type.

In this case there is an entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // Custom converter registered manually
    @Convert(converter = AccountTypeConverter.class)
    private AccountType type;

    private Double balance;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

and an enumerated field `AccountType`

```java
public enum AccountType {

    DEBIT("D"),

    CREDIT("C");
    private final String shortValue;

    private AccountType(String value) {
        this.shortValue = value;
    }

    public String getShortValue() {
        return shortValue;
    }

    private static final Function<String, AccountType> byShortValue = s ->
            Arrays.stream(values())
                    .filter(e -> e.getShortValue().equals(s))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid account type: " + s));

    public static AccountType fromShortValue(String shortValue) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(shortValue)
                .map(byShortValue)
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Finally, the instructed `AccountTypeConverter` should be like

```java
public class AccountTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<AccountType, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(AccountType attribute) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(attribute)
                .map(AccountType::getShortValue)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public AccountType convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return AccountType.fromShortValue(dbData);
    }
}
```

When opening an `Account`

```java
doInJPA(emFactory, em -> {
    var debit = new Account()
            .setId(1L)
            .setBalance(10_000d)
            .setType(AccountType.DEBIT);
    var credit = new Account()
            .setId(2L)
            .setBalance(30_000d)
            .setType(AccountType.CREDIT);
    em.persist(debit);
    em.persist(credit);
});
```

the generated SQL statements are like this

```sql
INSERT INTO account 
    (balance, type, id) 
VALUES (
    10000,
    'D',
    1
);

INSERT INTO account 
    (balance, type, id) 
VALUES (
    30000,
    'C',
    2
);
```

The previous example shows how to implement and register an attribute converter to a field of an enity. If you have multiple entities with the same type of enumerated field and all occurrences should be converted, then it is possible to **auto-register** the converter.

**Auto-registered `AttributeConverter`**

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class AccountTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<AccountType, String> {

    // implementation is same
}
```

In this case annotating the entity field is no longer necessary.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // Previously registered converter applied automatically
    private AccountType type;

    private Double balance;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes, I did mean JPA 2.1.  Didn't realize it woudl result in so much code!

Comment: @Dave in 2.0 you should implement a custom SQL type or UserType, then register the type definition both on the entity, and the entity attribute and to the sessionfactory. On the other hand implementing one interface with two methods is not so much. ;)